# Como puedo crear varias variables globales en Winforms C#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, variables, variables-globales

Me refiero a que por ejemplo tenga una variable llamada “A” en un formulario 1 y que pueda cambiar el valor de “A” desde el formulario 2 o 3 (todos)

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: No hay variables globales en C#, porque no hay un modulo global. Si no que todas son clases (hasta las pantallas). Tal vez si explicas un poco mas la logica atras de esto, podamos guiarte. E igual, la consulta parece un poco demasiado amplia

Comment: Lo que puedes usar seria el patrón Singleton para declarar todas las variables constantes en una clase y poder solo referenciarlas  como si fuera un "Helper".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

si mal no recuerdo, puedes acceder a esa variable incluyendo el nombre del formulario de origen en la llamada a la variable. Algo como:

En formulario 2:

```
Form1.A = "nuevo valor";
```

Comment: siempre y cuando: form1 se estatico, o form1 este declarado donde se esta accediendo.

Comment: @gbianchi Te creo, soy novata en c# , pero mis colegas me dijeron que podía acceder a objetos de otros forms de esa manera, por eso pensé que se podría. Sebastián tendría que probar :)

Comment: Fijate mi comentario en la pregunta. Si puedes acceder, la pregunta seria porque, y ademas siempre y cuando cumplas las condiciones de mi primer comentario a esta respuesta. y mas que creer lo que te dijeron, pruebalo ;)

Comment: @gbianchi Tranquilo ^^U Mis colegas me dijeron que podía acceder a una variable en otro form, y ya que lo pude hacer, por eso pensé que sería una respuesta posible para Seba.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Tal y como menciona @gbianchi, no hay un módulo global, y a menos que tu formulario sea estático directamente no podrías acceder a esa variable, pero puedes optar por una opción parecida usando [Encapsulamiento (Refactorización)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/a5adyhe9.aspx)

Ejemplo:

```
//Formulario 1...
 private string tuVariable = string.Empty;

 public string TuVariable
 {
      get { return tuVariable; }
      set { tuVariable = value; }
 }
```

> Pero para poder acceder a esta variable debes instanciar el `formulario1` desde donde desees acceder a la variable asi:

```
public partial class Formulario2 : Form
{
    public Formulario2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

   //......
   //......

   formulario1 frm = new formulario1();
   frm.TuVariable; //Aqui puedes asignarle valor o obtener su valor actual.
}
```

> Pero lo correcto sería crear una clase estática para acceder a las variables desde todos los formularios, algo así:

```
public static class TuClaseEstaticaCompartida
{
    public static string TuVariable;
    public static int OtraVariable;
    // otras variables estáticas
}
```

Y desde los demás formularios las llamas como cualquier otra variable común:

```
public void Formulario1()
{
    TuClaseEstaticaCompartida.TuVariable= textBox1.Text;
}

public void Formulario2()
{
    MessageBox.Show(TuClaseEstaticaCompartida.OtraVariable.ToString());
}
```

**Nota:** Las clases estáticas solo pueden tener miembros estáticos.

Comment: A qué te refieres con formulario estático? Como se puede hacer uno?

Comment: Me refiero al [Modificador `Static`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) ahí tienes información al respecto. No debes hacer un formulario estático, lo correcto es **crear una clase estática que de acceso a todas las variables que quieres compartir entre formularios**

Comment: Ya lo intente pero no me funciona, solo me funciona en 1 formulario

Comment: Lo estas haciendo mal que te muestra que no funciona? Coloca el código que has puesto en tu pregunta, para poder ayudarte, te fijaste bien en la declaración de las variables y el método de accedo? private, public, Mayúsculas, Minúsculas etc? , He editado la respuesta hechale un vistazo.

Comment: Esto así explicado está mucho mejor, Sebastián, como dije, soy novata, ahora yo también he aprendido con la respuesta de @J.Rodríguez. Mejor marca esta como la respuesta correcta ^_^